# Is it substandard if I have multiple tables in my database yet there's no relationship at all?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have multiple tables in my database. Some tables have relationship to others and some don't have. My friend told me that it is not advisable to have a table that is not related to others. Is it substandard if I have multiple tables in my database yet there's no relationship at all? Are there guidelines concerning to database table relationships?

And also, what are the guidelines in cascading tables?
thanks.

Comment: Well? Is there some relationship between the tables that you're not expressing? What are some examples of the tables that are unrelated?

Comment: for example, tables that are only meant for storage.

Comment: Storage of what? How are the tables of storing things used in the application?

Comment: storage of list of products . They are just used for viewing and sometimes we export it. It has nothing to do with the other data.

Comment: Could you describe the entire schema, what the application does and what the tables in question do?  You're not being very clear and its a bit hard to visualize what you have and the design around it (much less the design decisions that lead you to such a schema).

Comment: "Is it substandard if I have multiple tables in my database yet there's no relationship at all?" As a rule? No.

Comment: **Unclear what help you need.** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it isn't. I could name you many kinds of tables that are useful without being references by other tables. Just from memory:

- system parameters that control installation-specific settings on the software
- traits that record important update milestones which have already happened
- event traces logged to comply with legal requirements, but not used within the application (the law only requires that it be technically possible to reconstruct certain events, not that you code a module for doing that within your software)
- key words or tags entered by users - not the ones actually attached to user content items (those would be references by the items), but a list of *all* occurring tags, used for suggested auto-completions when users tag new items
- data that are regularly imported from external services, e.g. daily exchange rates: your application uses them, but obviously has no way if influencing them or even relating them to anything (that is the job of economy advisors, not of business software engineers)

Of course, the typical domain model will have many tables that reference each other, since models are all about structure, which is usually expressed as relationships between different entity types. But that doesn't mean you should artificially seek for relationships where there are none just to satisfy such a simplistic heuristic.